# Create a desktop shortcut to trigger Alt+Tab or Windows+Tab?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, shortcuts, autohotkey

I work through a VPN, and I RDP from my laptop into my main machine all the time.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd> don't work for me.  [The alternative shortcuts described here don't work for me.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Not sure if it's because of my laptop, or because it's a web RDP and not native RDP.

Is there a way I can create a desktop shortcut that I can click to trigger the effect of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

I do have AutoHotKey installed. Can I use a script to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Vbscript works fine here. I tested in RDP desktop though - both machines running Windows 10.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^%{TAB}"
```

Save the file with .vbs extension, such as `alttab.vbs` and place it on the desktop. Double-clicking it would show the Alt+Tab window (and the Alt Tab switcher screen remains until you select a program, or dismiss it.)

To send <kbd>WinKey</kbd>, you need NirCmd or any other program like AHK. With NirCmd, here is the command to simulate <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
nircmd.exe sendkeypress lwin+tab
```

[NirCmd Command Reference - sendkeypress](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/sendkeypress.html)

Comment: Thanks, That's exactly what I'm looking for. it's working on my local machine, but not on the remote one.  It might have something do with the fact that it's running Server 2012 R2.  I'm looking into that right now.

Comment: Tried option 2 above?

Comment: Ugh, it's blocked by my company.  I'll have to give it a try later.

Comment: Got it downloaded.  Do I just call that from a batch file?

Comment: You may create a normal desktop shortcut to it. Batch would work fine as well.

Comment: Thanks... it works on windows 10 and not server 2012.  Same as other example :(  I'll dig into server 2012 and see if I can find the reason these are blocked.

Comment: Either way, both your solutions are excellent.  Thanks so much for your help.  No matter what, you got me 5 steps closer to a solution.

Comment: Glad the info helped. Don't have a Server 2012 machine here to test, unfortunately.